# Who is the winning constructor for a particular race?

Tags: formula-1

When the podium ceremony is held, the top three drivers are up there along with one team principal. I assume that the team principal is that of the winning constructor for that particular race.

Let's say that Hamilton finished P1, Sainz P2, and Verstappen P3, while their team-mates retired. Then, Tsunoda and Gasly were P4 and P5. So, the winning constructor for that race should be the team of Tsunoda and Gasly (AlphaTauri), right?

Comment: Why would AlphaTauri be the winning constructor in that scenario? They would only earn 22 points (23 with fastest lap), whereas Mercedes would earn 25 points (26 with fastest lap).

Answer (score 5):

The winning constructor for a race is simply the constructor for whom the winning driver raced. In your example, Mercedes would be the winning constructor, because their driver, Lewis Hamilton, won the race. It would therefore be Mercedes team principal Toto Wolff (or another Mercedes team member - it's not *always* the team principal these days) on the podium with Hamilton, Sainz, and Verstappen.

You can confirm this by checking the "Results" section for any given season on Wikipedia - the winning driver and winning constructor will always match. [Here are the 2020 results, for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Formula_One_World_Championship#Grands_Prix).